# In chrome 81 version, set gridOptions.defaultColDef.autoHeight = true of ag-grid, browser crashes or gets stuck when I call api.resetRowHeights

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

- The specific version of the browser is Google Chrome81.0.4044.92,Previous versions such as 76 did not have this problem
- I use React,
- This problem occurs only when I open the browser developer tools

Comment: try using Chrome Canary, if the problem still happens, report it Chromium

Comment: The Chrome Canary also have this problem...

Comment: Can you try and create a plunkr that reproduces this issue? See this https://plnkr.co/edit/1oKqyPiOJTS6QxkS?preview - The browser isn't crashing...

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem on plunkr, I suspect that it is related to the complexity of our project, I will continue to track, if there is a problem, I will come back.